# Getting Error : platform DatabasePlatform does not support NativeSequence

Tags: java, jpa, junit, eclipselink, spring-batch

I am trying to write junit test cases for a Java Spring batch application, DAO layer. When I configure a Data Layer Object with custom sequence generator, and run the test case I am getting the below Exception.

**Exception Description: SEQ_EMPLOYEE_ID: platform DatabasePlatform does not support NativeSequence.**

For data Persistence i am using JPA+EclipseLink.

Below mentioned the configuration files I use for Junit.

**DO Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
@NamedQuery(name = "test.test",
        query = "SELECT d FROM EmployeeDO d where d.status = 'COMPLETED'")
public class EmployeeDO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SequenceGenerator(name = "employeeIdSequence", allocationSize = 1,
            sequenceName = "SEQ_EMPLOYEE_ID")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "employeeIdSequence")
    @Column(name = "BATCH_ID")
    private long batchId;

}
```

**JunitPersistence.xml**

```
persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="eclipseLinkPunitEmployee" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>org.batch.model.data.EmployeeDO</class>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
          <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:dataSource"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.id-validation" value="NULL"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Test Context XML**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="entityManagerFactory"   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="eclipseLinkPunitEmployee" />
    <property name='dataSource' ref='junitDatasource' />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:JunitPersistence.xml" />
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />
        </map>
    </property>
  </bean>  
  <jdbc:embedded-database id="junitDatasource" type="HSQL">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:sequences.sql"/>
  </jdbc:embedded-database>
```

**sequences.sql**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_EMPLOYEE_ID START WITH 1 increment by 1;
CREATE TABLE DUAL (DUMMY DECIMAL);
INSERT INTO DUAL VALUES(1);
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native sequence objects are specific to the database being used - you need to specify the correct database platform that should be used for native Sequences to work.  You will need to add the [target-database](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/p_target_database.htm) persistence property to specify the database if it isn't being picked up from or set by Spring.

Comment: Added <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Oracle"/> in persistence XML.
It works!! Thanks..